# How to find the best values for a and b using optimization.curve_fit. in python. I keep getting an error for my func

Tags: python

I am trying to find the best values for my model y = aX +b by using optimization.curve_fit but keep getting the following error:

func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

My code is as follows:

def func(x, y, a, b):
return y == a*x + b

```
xdata = np.array(time1_list)
ydata = np.array(phi1_list)
# Initial guess.
x0    = np.array([0.0, 0.0])

print(optimization.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, x0))
```

I have tried using this optimization method but cannot seem to get past this error. The data consists of 2 lists, xdata and ydata. My model is y = ax+b.

Eventually I will be using a least squares fit to find the optimum values of a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the definition of your function like this:

```
def func(x, a, b): 
    y = a*x + b
    return y
```

Here is full exemple:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def func(x, a, b): 
    y = a*x + b
    return y

xdata = np.linspace(1, 10, 100)
y = func(xdata, 2, 5)
rng = np.random.default_rng()
y_noise = rng.normal(size=xdata.size) *0.2
ydata = y + y_noise


# Initial guess.
x0    = np.array([0.0, 0.0])

# print(optimization.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, x0))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, x0)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

plt.xlabel('x')

plt.ylabel('y')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

You will get the figure :
[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, how would i plot this with lists as my xdata and ydata?

Comment: Just copy my code and change the line from `xdata = ... ` to `ydata =  y + y_noise` as your code : `xdata = np.array(time1_list)`  and `ydata = np.array(phi1_list)`